# Deleting in Muticursor results in unexpected behavior?

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets, multicursorediting

Deleting in Multicursor snippets seem to not work. The cursor collapses in the first instance, and doesn't delete in the second instance. See video.

https://media.giphy.com/media/1jZuNl4WPuNory4awF/giphy.gif

This is the LaTeX snippet, I've tried replacing later occurrences with $1 as well. The same behavior occurs.

```
"Multicursor placeholder": {
        "prefix": "test",
        "body": "${1:x} ${1:x} some text ${1:x} other text",
        "description": "breaking multicursor"
    },
```

When expanding the snippet, and trying to replace the `x` character with a `y`, deleting pressing backspace does not delete the input in the later occurrences of

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this behavior.

Comment: Thanks for trying @Mark I figured out it's an issue with the vim extension, not VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else running into this issue, it's a known issue in the vscodevim extension.

https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues/1946

The workaround right now is is `ctrl-backspace` instead of backspace.